# Building SQLite DLL with VS2015

Tags: visual-c++, dll, sqlite, shared-libraries

I'm trying to build SQLite as a DLL from [sources](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html). In the [the "How to"](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html) section of the website, they give a simple command line to build it :

```
cl sqlite3.c -link -dll -out:sqlite3.dll
```

When I try this command, I get the DLL but not the ".lib" file. With the DLL only I cannot use SQLite inside another dev project. Without the .lib file, there are some symbols missing.

Answer (score 1):

> here are some notes i made a while ago on creating a *sqlite3.lib* file using the contents of *sqlitedll-X_X_X.zip* (and some other files). This approach might differ from your intended approach - but it may get your project started - I hope it helps.

1. create *\tmp* folder in your project directory
2. find the following 3 files (on the web) and then copy them into the *\tmp* directory: ***lib.exe, link.exe, mspdb80.dll***
3. from the latest *sqlitedll-X_X_X.zip* file (i used: *http://www.sqlite.org/sqlitedll-3_7_3.zip)* copy *sqlite3.def* and *sqlite3.dll* to *\tmp* directory
4. open command line (terminal) and navigate to *\tmp* directory
5. create *.LIB* file by typing:

   LIB /DEF:sqlite3.def /MACHINE:X86
6. copy  the newly created  *sqlite3.lib*   file to your project directory

make sure that the following files are in the project directory:

- *sqlite3.h* (from: *http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-amalgamation-X_X_X.zip*)
- *sqlite3.dll* (from: *http://www.sqlite.org/sqlitedll-X_X_X.zip*)

also

- add the *sqlite3.h* file to the project
- make sure that the linker can see *sqlite3.lib*

Answer (score 0):

For those trying to do this with CMake, and assuming that you are building from amalgamation sources, to produce the `.lib` file when building a shared variant on Windows you need to add a compile definition `SQLITE_API=__declspec(dllexport)`, for example:

```
project("SQLite3"
    VERSION 3.39.1
    DESCRIPTION "Small, fast, self-contained, high-reliability, full-featured SQL database engine"
    LANGUAGES C
)

# ...

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME})

# ...

if(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
    if(WIN32)
        target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME}
           PRIVATE
               "SQLITE_API=__declspec(dllexport)"
        )
    else() # haven't tested that
        target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME}
           PRIVATE
               "SQLITE_API=__attribute__((visibility(\"default\")))"
        )
    endif()
endif()

# ...
```